# Javac 17 type inference on ternary operator

Tags: java, type-inference

While migrating from Java 11 to Java 17, I've stumbled on a compilation error on a method that looks like this (using javac):

```
public List<String> getList() {
    return true ? Collections.emptyList() : new ArrayList(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

The class is compiled with `-source 7 -target 7`, it compiles fine with Java 7, 8 and 11, but with Java 17 the following error appears:

```
    error: incompatible types: List<Object> cannot be converted to List<String>
            return true ? Collections.emptyList() : new ArrayList(new ArrayList<String>());
                        ^
```

The error disappears if `-source 7 -target 7` is removed.

Why does this happen? Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Any reason you're still using `new ArrayList` rather than `new ArrayList<>`? Java 7 supports the diamond operator. I'm also curious about that empty list argument...

Comment: @ernest_k what's the issue with an empty argument?

Comment: And a simpler example: ```return true ? Collections.emptyList() : new ArrayList<>();``` also doesn't work? I assume that 'true' is replacing some conditions.

Comment: Note that the example is absurd, this is just to illustrate the syntax triggering the error.

Comment: When I try this on Java 17, I only get an "unchecked conversion" *warning*. Maybe the code that produces the error is actually different? @EmmanuelBourg

Comment: @Beri It works with the diamond operator, that's how I've fixed the error. But I'd like to understand why it happened.

Comment: @f1sh question is why do that at all? `new ArrayList<String>()` produces the same thing as `new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<String>())`

Comment: @ernest_k If you add `-source 7` javac will return an error

Comment: @f1sh because the code that inspired this exemple returns a defensive copy of an existing list, in the example I've replaced it with an inlined ArrayList instanciation to keep the syntax short.

Comment: It does *not* work with the diamond operator when using `-source 7`, as Java 7’s type inference is not capable of inferring `List<String>` for `Collections.emptyList()` here. The fix would require `Collections.<String>emptyList()`. It’s debatable whether using a raw type on the other branch should allow passing the inferred `List<Object>` as `List<String>`.

Comment: @Holger you are right, the diamond operator worked in the original code (with different generic types) but not in this reduced example.